# Hair Particles move on their own

Tags: particles

I want to create a Pinata effect on pants. I created hair particles  for each color but here's the problem - when i animate movement of the pants, the particles kinda move on their own
No matter what settings i give them, i always have that issue.

The weirdest thing is - moving object in  viewport is ok, it's only when i playback the animation, it looks strange. What can i do? Thanks =)

You can check the video on https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/179gqs9/hair_particles_move_on_their_own/

Comment: Are there modifiers on the model? A Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/